# Having trouble trying to obtain value from Firebase

Tags: swift, firebase, firebase-realtime-database

I'm trying to get a value inside a Firebase database I set up but I'm having issues trying get it out. There is a section in my program where I go through each child under `Cities` and obtain the the name of each city. I thought it would be a good idea to try to obtain the status for each city in the same section but I can't get it out. Below is a sample of the JSON object. I feel like I'm close but missing something to put it all together.

```
"Users" : {
    "NPNBig20BXNpX4Rz0UbMyiKAarY2" : {
      "Cities" : {
        "New York City" : {
          "Status" : "Empty"
        },
        "Atlanta" : {
          "Status" : "Empty"
        },
        "Test City" : {
          "Status" : "Wow",
          "Value" : "Test"
        }
      },
      "Email" : "fakeemail@gmail.com"
    }
  }
```

Code:

```
guard let uid = userID else { return }
    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://testApp.firebaseio.com/").child("Users").child(uid).child("Cities")
    var dataTest : [String] = []
    //var cityDictionary: [String:String]()
    databaseRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let key = snap.key
            guard let value = snap.value else { return }
            //let testData = value["Status"] **Type Any has no subscript
            print("Key: ", key, "\nValue: ", value)
            dataTest.append(key)
        }
        completion(dataTest)
    })
```

This is the printed output

```
Key:  New York City 
Value:  {
    Status = Empty;
}
Key:  Sintra 
Value:  {
    Status = Empty;
}
Key:  Test City 
Value:  {
    Status = Wow;
    Value = Test;
}
```

Comment: what `print("Key: ", key, "\nValue: ", value)` prints?

Comment: @RichieRich Added the print out the question

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is the way you can get `Status` from your `value`:

```
if let value = snap.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
    let Status = value["Status"] as? String ?? ""
}
```

And your complete code will be:

```
guard let uid = userID else { return }
    let databaseRef = Database.database().reference(fromURL: "https://testApp.firebaseio.com/").child("Users").child(uid).child("Cities")
    var dataTest : [String] = []
    //var cityDictionary: [String:String]()
    databaseRef.observeSingleEvent(of: .value, with: {(snapshot) in
        for child in snapshot.children {
            let snap = child as! DataSnapshot
            let key = snap.key
            guard let value = snap.value else { return }
            //let testData = value["Status"] **Type Any has no subscript
            if let value = snap.value as? [String: AnyObject] {
                let Status = value["Status"] as? String ?? ""
            }
            print("Key: ", key, "\nValue: ", value)
            dataTest.append(key)
        }
        completion(dataTest)
    })
```

Answer (score 0):

```
func handleGetCities(_ completion: @escaping ([String]) -> ()) {
    guard let uid = Auth.auth().currentUser?.uid else { return }
    // OR
    guard let uid = userID else { return }
    // THEN
    var data: [String] = []
    let reference = Database.database().reference()
    reference.child("Users").child(uid).child("Cities").observe(.childAdded, with: { (snapshot) in

        let city_name = snapshot.key
        data.append(city_name)
        completion(data)

    }, withCancel: nil)
}
```